# Canvas app framing issue (how to define domain of RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp)

Tags: lightning, oauth2, canvas, mydomain, authorization

We implemented a tool which uses salesforce oauth.

This tool should be included into an opportunity page as canvas app.

First of all: The oauth2 workflow works fine when I open the tool in a new browser tab.

We use the KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle ( https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle ).

When an authorization is required, the user is redirected to 
https://**foo--bar.lightning.force.com**/services/oauth2/authorize?baz

*I already tried several configurations (config yaml file) instead of foo--bar.lightning.force.com - e.g. test.salesforce.com .*

All of the options I tried redirect to 
https://foo--bar.**cs83.my.** salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?baz

This is fine until I try to open the app within a lighning opportunity template.

The canvas app is included in a page which is located here:
foo--bar.**lightning.force**.com

This leads (of course) to security problems and loading of the canvas app content is blocked:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://foo--bar.cs83.my.salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=(...)id0:j_id1:canvasapp
>   does not permit framing.

Do anybody know what to do in this case or how to configure the domain of RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage?